# Reading a binary file produces only Null values

Tags: java, binaryfiles

When i try to read a binary file and print its contents it only produces a bunch of Nulls in the Console output.

I have tried many different methods and ideas i have found online but none have worked for me, i keep getting the same "Null" results

```
public void decode(String fileName) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(fileName);
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while(inputFile.available()>0) {
            message = inputFile.readUTF();  
                    System.out.println(message);
        }   
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

The file is a binary file which contains 'n' number of bytes.  Each one is supposed to be read and printed out. In my main method i call this method and pass the file path as the parameter. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you see `null` on your console, that's because the code that wrote the file put the text `"null"` in the file. Look at the code that writes the file, there's something wrong in there. The method `readUTF` on `DataInputStream` cannot return the value `null` (see the Javadoc), but it can return the String `"null"`.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand the root of the problem from your question. Like @GhostCat suggested, you should create a minimal example.

But I believe this might solve your problem:

```
Path path = Paths.get("SomeBinaryFile.dat");
byte[] fileContents =  Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

And then do with that array whatever you want.

Since a byte includes 8 bits you can access the first 8 bits by fileContents[0] and then probably control the flow of your program using bitwise operations.

More about `readAllBytes(...)` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)

Hope this helps. Good luck.